# Wordpress page not found issue

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've created a custom post type "equipment" and a page that will list all posts of this type. The page is created with a custom template "template-equipment.php", and resides at `www.example.com/equipment`. This works fine.

I can create a new equipment post no problem, but when I go to view it at `/equipment/newitem`, I get `page not found`.

Here's the code that I used to create the post type:

```
function equipment_post_type() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                => 'equipment',
    'singular_name'       => 'Item',
    'menu_name'           => 'Equipment',
    'parent_item_colon'   => 'Parent Item:',
    'all_items'           => 'All Items',
    'view_item'           => 'View Item',
    'add_new_item'        => 'Add New Item',
    'add_new'             => 'Add New Item',
    'edit_item'           => 'Edit Item',
    'update_item'         => 'Update Item',
    'search_items'        => 'Search Item',
    'not_found'           => 'Not found',
    'not_found_in_trash'  => 'Not found in Trash',
);
$args = array(
    'label'               => 'equipment',
    'description'         => 'Equipment Description',
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array( 'title', ),
    'taxonomies'          => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 5,
    'menu_icon'           => '',
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'capability_type'     => 'page',
);
register_post_type( 'equipment', $args );

}
```

Does this somehow conflict with the page `/equipment`?

Comment: MAy be category name and page name is conflicting

Comment: May be as simple as updating your permalinks (no need to change them, just re-save).

Comment: @Hobo this was the correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add your code before or after this code in function.php

```
add_action( 'init', 'equipment_post_type' );

// your wholecode
```

After Add this code update your permalink  this code is worked after this step.